# Angular 2 оптимизация компонентов

Tags: angular2

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-settings-departaments',
  templateUrl: './settings-departaments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./settings-departaments.component.scss']
})
export class SettingsDepartamentsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
   create() {
  }
  delete() {
  }
  update() {
  }
}
```

Есть 3 похожих компонента.

- SettingsDepartamentsComponent,
- SettingsSchedulesComponent,
- SettingsPositionsComponent

Их задача в систему добавлять, редактировать и удалять данные из базы данных через api. Данные практически все одинаковые.

Структура данных у них похожа очень.

[image: Скрин]

Api так же одинаков.

```
 GET|HEAD  | api/departaments   
 POST      | api/departaments
 GET|HEAD  | api/departaments/{departament}
 PUT|PATCH | api/departaments/{departament}
 DELETE    | api/departaments/{departament}

 GET|HEAD  | api/positions   
 POST      | api/positions
 GET|HEAD  | api/positions/{position}
 PUT|PATCH | api/positions/{position}
 DELETE    | api/positions/{position}
```

Подскажите как можно оптимизировать процесс создания подобных компонентов?
Даже не создание. А каким образом это можно реализовать в одном компоненте?

Comment: Передавайте в компонент соответствующие параметры, делайте соответствующие запросы, отображайте полученные данные соответствующим образом. Ваш вопрос сейчас выглядит как "напишите за меня код". Что вы пробовали делать и что у вас не получалось или не устраивало?

Comment: Можно создать один базовый класс, в котором будут методы для сохранения, получения данных. Также там могут быть свойства, для настроек(анпример, url). Потом от этого базового класса наследуйте ваши компоненты.